# Postgres SELECT does not show correct result

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have a table Order with columns Id,Name,Code in my db.
When I execute, lets say

```
 SELECT * FROM Order
```

I get two records:

```
Id,Name,Code
1,FirstOrder,165y
2,SecondOrder,165y
```

Two orders with same code, everything is ok!
But when I try to find by code:

```
SELECT * from ORDER where code = '165y'
```

I got only single row as result:

```
Id,Name,Code
1,FirstOrder,165y
```

Second order is not shown,despite the fact that it has same code.
But if I try this:

```
SELECT * from Order where lower(code) = '165y'
```

I get two rows again:

```
    Id,Name,Code
1,FirstOrder,165y
2,SecondOrder,165y
```

It seems to me that these rows got the same code value: '165y', but looks like postgres differs them in some way.
Postgres Version - 9.3.17,
Code column type - varchar(50).

What could be the problem? I have no idea even where to search.
Need help.

Comment: I think the second one is written in other character code. I will look like the latin character 'y' but it is other code. You can check this by run this query with each data in each row `select a, ascii(a) from regexp_split_to_table([your words],'') t(a)`

Comment: Column collation?

Comment: @MabuKloesen nice idea. I 'll check

Comment: Try `SELECT code::bytea FROM order WHERE id = 2;` in `psql` and show what you get.

Comment: same result for both: '165®ü'

Answer (score 0):

Problem was partly resolved.
The main reason of such behavior is that
searching like

```
SELECT * from Order where lower(code) = '165y'
```

uses Seq Scan, when query

```
SELECT * from ORDER where code = '165y'
```

searching with bitmap index scan using unique index on code field.

I still have no idea how could duplicates values occur with unique index.
So I've just drop this index, cleaned duplicates and created index again.

Comment: 9.3.16 fixed a bug where indexes created using `concurrently` might not have been created correctly. Those indexes would need to be re-created: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/release-9-3-16.html#AEN115710 Maybe you were affected by that, but did not rebuild the index

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name no, index was create just like CREATE UNIQUE INDEX, without concurrently